# Does using a Range to get part of a string create a new string in memory?

Tags: c#, string, range

By using the C# 8 feature Range, does it create a new string in memory or does it provide a "pointer" to the memory parts of the previous string already there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
var x = "foo"[1..2];
```

Is [compiled](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjQG4CGATogB6IC8iARAGYD2fLgG0IAOlFgAugG5qOAL6x5QA===) to;

```cs
int num = 1;
int length = 2 - num;
"foo".Substring(num, length);
```

And `.Substring` will create a new copy of the characters.

If you don't need a string, you could use `"foo".AsSpan()[1..2];`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following your question. A range of a `string` is not a `string`, its an array of `char`. `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

If you want a substring, then you should use `string.Substring`, and yes, it will create a new `string`.